# Workspaces reduced to 1 after activating Compiz

Tags: compiz, workspaces

I could not activate the cube rotation between workspaces. After checking out various compiz settings, I found out that on activating compiz the 4 workspaces merge to 1 and leaving me no option to add workspaces or switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

Open ccsm and go to General Options > Desktop Size and you will find the option for Horizontal Virtual Size there.

Increase this value to > 1.